# Password Policies : Salesforce Commnunites

Tags: community, forgot-your-password, change-password

I am developing a custom Salesforce Community, where in I have developed a custom Password Confirmation page.

The current functionality is working fine. I just need to compare the old password while setting up a new password (currently Salesforce functionality is doing this).Can you kindly let me know as to how I can check for the same in Controller class and then throw a message to user saying that "Password cannot be same as Previous 3 password".

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

If you call Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword), doesn't it though an exception if you violate the password policy?